# Add (click) in button using thymeleaf

Tags: angular, thymeleaf

I want to append (click) attribute in my button using thymeleaf:

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"th:attrappend="${'(click)=searchUsers(' + companyType+')'}" >search</button>
```

But the above codes is not working.Normally, It should be look like this:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"(click)="searchUsers" >search</button>
```

What is wrong am I doing?

Comment: I don't think this is possible in thymeleaf... I tried several ways to get thymeleaf to generate an attribute "(click)", but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

You may try `th:click="searchUsers"`, this should do the work.

Answer (score 0):

**If you just want to call a javascript function**

If you mean calling a javascript function named `searchUsers()` you can do the following:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" th:onclick="'searchUsers()'" >search</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function searchUsers() {
        // ...
    }
</script>
```

To pass arguments to the javascript function it looks like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" th:onclick="'searchUsers(\'' + ${companyType} + '\')'" >search</button>
```

If you want to call a backend function you have to use ajax inside of searchUsers().

**If you exactly want the `(click)="searchUsers"` code in your button**

In this case thymeleaf removes the brackets. But you can write your own thymeleaf dialect with a custom processor to handle this.

For example:

```
public class AngularClickProcessor extends AbstractAttributeTagProcessor {

    public AngularClickProcessor(final int precedence) {
        super(TemplateMode.HTML, "angular", null, false, "click", true,
            precedence, true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doProcess(ITemplateContext context,
            IProcessableElementTag tag, AttributeName attributeName,
            String attributeValue,
            IElementTagStructureHandler structureHandler) {

        structureHandler.removeAttribute(attributeName);
        structureHandler.setAttribute("(click)", attributeValue);

    }

}
```

And

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" angular:click="searchUsers" >search</button>
```

The result will be:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="searchUsers">search</button>
```

Comment: Thymeleaf provide a better syntax: th:onclick="|searchUsers(${companyType})|"